# How to trap error with a transactional annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I use spring boot 2.2.

In a method with transactional anocation, when I save via repository if there is no error, I want to send a message with rabbit mq.

How to be sure there is no error with repository?

```
@Transactional
public void save(CreditEvent creditEvent) {
    repository.save(creditEvent);
    //no error send message
}
```

if there is an error when sending message, I don't want to rollback saving operation.

Comment: If save failed `DataAccessException` exception will be thrown and flow won't continue, no?

Comment: can't said, will all theses annotation, there is a lot of magical stuff done automatically

Comment: Then separate the saving and sending in different transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's Transactional and JPA, still it's a java method which if save failed then unchecked [DataAccessException](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html) exception will be thrown and flow won't continue to send message.

> class is a **runtime exception, there is no need for user code to catch it** or subclasses if any error is to be considered fatal (the usual case).

Comment: so no need to catch and if there is an error when sending a message is done (JmsException - checked JMSException converted to unchecked) I need to add noRollbackFor if i want to avoid rollback (saving operation when there is an error to send information?

Comment: @roberttrudel so why not moving message logic outside @Transactional?

Answer (score -1):

```
    @Transactional
    public void save(CreditEvent creditEvent) {
      try {    
        repository.save(creditEvent);
        //no error send message}
      catch {
        // send message 
        // rethrow error 
      }
    }
```

Comment: That won't work as the exception will occur after the commit of the transaction, which happens after the call to the `@Transactional save` method, not after the `repository.save`.

Comment: if there is an error (DataAccessException), a roll back will be done

Comment: @M.Deinum that will work ! Because the `repository.save(...)` is in an transaction rolledback by any exception AND the possible exception is re-throwned.

Comment: It won't. The catch will never be reached as the try/catch has to be around the outer method. At least when doing things with a write behind persistence solution like JPA or  unless you flush everything manually which will kill the performance.